My boss gave my project to the new employee, what do I do now?
To give you some background:
About me: I joined the company in 2022 as my first job, right after I finished grad school at a top university. I am more of a technical person, but I took quite some business classes so I know the basics and am willing to learn from the process. I am a foreign citizen and just got my work visa (sponsored by this company).
About the company: It is a small US company in a traditional industry and generates revenue by applying for gov grants and creating start-ups. My team only has a handful of people and usually, each team member leads one project. I was the youngest among the team.
Existing conflict: I chose to wear masks since COVID. On some important occasions (such as client meetings) I do take it off to avoid confusion. Since 2023 my manager (we only have one management level below the CEO) started accusing me of "lack of collaboration" because of the mask and recently this accusation has been upgraded to "I don't think you have the confidence to interact with industry partners and promote the company because of the mask", despite that it was not true and he knew just a month ago I was at an event socializing our products.

So when I joined the company, I was handed a small grant. I worked my ass off in the following year as a newbie and got us the much larger subsequent grant, during which I did everything on my own: R&D, commercialization plan, business development, etc. My manager said he could help me but the company lacked a systematic training mechanism and he was always too busy, so not really.
Several months ago, a new employee who has ~10 years of experience in the industry joined the company. I respect his track record and I thought I could learn a lot from him, so I proposed to let him help me with business outreach, which aligns with his experience. The team environment has always been great and we help each other out without hesitation. Oh man, I was wrong about my new colleague. He kept asking me to hand him information and invite him to every meeting, he took my work and socialized them with potential partners, and he frequently had individual chats with my manager & CEO without my awareness. I thought he was just trying hard to do well, until a couple of months later my manager called a meeting for three of us and announced that my colleague would now be leading the commercialization work of my project.
The announcement was made without any prior communication with me, I was not happy but I decided to respect the executive decision and try my best to work together with him. With that being said, I was still leading all the R&D and PM tasks.
However, after that day my colleague constantly attempted to act like my superior, and actually, he was very good at manipulating situations. I stood my ground when necessary but for a large part of it, I had to cave in to avoid making myself look like the non team-player.
Two months ago we had a small argument about budgeting. We carved out a small portion of the budget for government outreach (initiated by me but he took over), and at that time it was already way overrun, so I proposed that we either reduce the work or turn it into an internal business development project to ensure we have enough budget for the R&D work (the grant was for r&d). He was pissed and he confronted me in front of the manager, and we reached a temporary agreement.
Everything seemed alright again until today when I had my year-end review with my manager. He once again accused me of being non-collaborative and lacking "outward interaction confidence" because I wear the mask. As a result, he decided to let my colleague fully own the project, and I now only serve as a supporting technical personnel. I kinda knew something would happen as my manager started to pick on me a week ago, giving me $hit for tiny things that he doesn't like and making insulting racial jokes in front of the whole team on a daily basis. The r&d work was almost done, so I understood that the focus needed to shift to commercialization, but how he processed it was simply humiliating.
I responded to his comments professionally and tried my best to comply with his demands and make him happy. If it was me three years ago I would have resigned but now the work visa is holding me back. Reporting to HR doesn't do me any good in small companies, and I am now considering the next phase of my career.
So now I would like to get some advice from you. What did I do wrong & What could I have done to avoid this situation? What can I do now to make my life easier before I move on? If any of you had similar experiences, what did you do?
I do feel much better through venting, and I would like to thank you all for helping me.

What country are you in? In the UK, what you've described here would essentially be an instant win for you in an employment tribunal for harrassment, doubly so if your manager were making racist jokes.

Hello Philip, Thanks for the information! I am in the US (just added). Unfortunately, I am in a red state and my manager is a republican (and I am not a US citizen), so the office environment has always been on the tolerant side of such jokes as long as they don't mean any harm, which I wasn't a fan of but accepted. I knew this time he was picking on me, but I wasn't looking to make a case out of it and defeat him, I only wanted a smooth transition toward the next phase of my career now. It does feel horrible and you are right, it should not be tolerated in the office, but I am constrained :(

You may wish to look for another company where you have a better relationship with the manager. Two years at your first job out of school is a good time to get a better paying job.

Do you wear mask because of a medical implication? If so, there is an ADA aspect.

Thanks, David and Michael, and yes I am preparing to move on. I have consulted my Doc and the conclusion is that because of my asthma, the risk and consequence of me getting COVID is much greater, that's why I am still wearing it.

@CrikP You need to include that asthma aspect in your question.  Comments here are treated as being ephemeral, and can be deleted or moved to chat with zero notice or input by you.

Rolled back the removal of the question.  Please dont do this.  Answers in the answer section please.

Are you sure that the perception of your lack of collaboration is entirely due to the mask?  Or could you be blaming that when there may be other ways you're not fully engaging with your colleagues?

(FWIW, my personal view is that wearing a mask shouldn't incur any shame or disapproval; it has proven health benefits in some cases, and a few years ago we all wore them and we all coped.  In some ways it's a pity that more people don't still wear them and keep them visible and ‘normalised’.)

@gidds I regularly attend events with 50-70 people, and there's always a couple of people wearing a mask.  I don't judge them over that.  Not my body, not my choice.

@jwenting it is very rude of you to make such an assumption.

@gidds thanks, and mostly yes, he was very explicit about it. The other possible angle is that because of the mask I chose to have lunch at my desk most of the time, that's pretty much it. without lunchtime chit chat building personal bonding with the team was slower, but it has been 2 years and I am pretty sure we are beyond that.

A person with 10 years of experience in the industry is taking over a project that is maturing from a person that has had one job from straight out of grad school?
Are you 100% sure that this situation is about the people and none of it is about the product?
People that are great at R&D are not usually the best outward facing people. Yes, that is painting with a wide brush but it is true way more than not.
The company's job is in part to ensure the best outcome for the product (to make money). Which person at this point is likely to make that happen?
You have two real choices, accept this situation or fight it.
Accept this situation and there is a great deal you can learn for your career growth. You have a new product that will look good on your CV and an experienced person that you can turn into your mentor. All you need to do is convince them that you've seen the light.
Fight the situation and you have no path forward at this company. Then you have to be concerned about visas, etc. It will be a complete setback personally and professionally.
The choice is yours.
Unfortunately, I am in a red state and my manager is a republican 
(and I am not a US citizen),

This statement says a lot more about your attitude than the workplace's. WHY? Because you aren't saying something that this person has done, you are stating that their politics are icky to you. If they are telling racist jokes, that is bad behavior not politics. Be specific and call them out.
Be a professional, don't care what someone's politics are. How they act at work is what matters.

Strongly advise the OP not to fight this. The colleague with more experience is quite rightly the one in charge, and wearing a mask at this time is an overreaction, red state or blue state.

Also, wearing a face mask several years after a brief period it was remotely accepted  AND after receiving repeated notifications about it... will send some strong not-a-team player vibes. Or I-have-confidence-issues...

I mean, if OP worse it constantly and didn't take it off during important meetings.. Then I would be understanding, the media caused a lot of hypochondria among easily influenced people. But the fact that OP takes it off for meetings where they are in close proximity to other people, tells me that OP is just virtual signaling and doesn't really believe the mask is doing anything...

That statement about political affiliation was to simply pointing out the fact that the media has resulted in a hostile/biased view for people like my manager against specific nationals, we all know that, no need to be sensitive, and I clearly said what this person done because of this bias, I have chosen to act professionally and not to talk back. Going back to the topic, in fact I did exactly the first option, and my goal is to make the most of it when I still can. Thanks for the advice.

@CrikP When it comes to politics and the media be skeptical. The media makes their money by promoting controversy in many cases. Good luck. Turn this into great opportunity that in 10 years you'll laugh about.

@DogBoy37 what I was more concerned about was how my boss uses this almost as an excuse/justification for him to act unprofessionally against me on a personal level, but hey there's nothing I can do, he's the boss:)

@CrikP  How I behaved 40 years ago and how I behave today is different. Not that I would say that I was ever racist or crossed lines, but I would put up with jokes from others that came close to the line. Today, I would politely say something like "what do you mean by that?" when he misbehaves. Also, consider letting HR know about the health issue. There is no reason to be bullied. You have 2 distinct issues here.

Are you sure that you are wearing the mask for the reason you portray to the outside? Are you sure that wearing the mask is a balanced risk avoidance stragtegy? If you have a strong medical reason it may be rational, but it could be that your manager does not know.
Towards your project: It seems that it was sucessful, since it is commercialized now. It is completly normal for me that the commercialization phase needs other people than the research phase. There are many projects which i was involved in for years where somebody else, usually more  senior took over (I am more the R&D type of person).

Sascha, I have consulted my Doc and the conclusion is that because of my asthma the risk and consequence of me getting COVID is much greater, that's why I am wearing it, and everyone in the office knows about it. I agree with what you said, and I was fine with the executive decision, it was just the way he treated me made me feel uncomfortable I guess. Thanks.


What did I do wrong & What could I have done to avoid this situation?

Stop wearing a mask. 55% of communication is thru facial expressions.
Do you know who wear masks? Bank robbers, muggers, and terrorists. People who have something to hide. It makes you seem less trustworthy/ it is harder to communicate with you.

What can I do now to make my life easier before I move on?

Talk to a Psychologist to help you deal with whatever mental trauma that you have that has you still wearing a mask even though you aren't sick and we have a vaccine that works for covid-19 about as well as the flu vaccine works. By wearing a mask while everyone else on the team is not, this makes you stand out as different, weird and quite likely some type of basket case. Your boss who has been telling you to ditch the mask? He's been trying to help you.

If any of you had similar experiences, what did you do?

Can't help you here. Never had this issue, I don't like customer socialization, am not a big fan of product management and shove that on whoever I can manage to cajole, blackmail, or con into doing it so that I can focus on the fun technical stuff.

I have had healthy coworkers choose to wear N95 masks all the time, not because they were concern with about their health, but because they had family members that were immune compromised and did not want to chance bringing anything from work home.

Yeah, and said person doesn't selectively wear it as OP does... It is one thing if the person wears it 100% of the time, but "On some important occasions (such as client meetings) I do take it off to avoid confusion."  OP isn't wearing it all the time. They take it off occasionally.  When dealing with clients, who are more likely to infect you with an unfamilar disease then your co-workers are (due to travel).

Thanks, Anketam, for your understanding. Questor, I think I was clear on my motivation, if I had the chance I would wear it 100% of the time. It is called risk assessment, I put something more important before my health, you don't need to keep criticizing my mask-wearing to prove anything. In fact, I got along with everyone else on my team and we've always worked together well. My manager is the only one who thinks that there is a problem.

While the advice on the impact of wearing a mask is sound, the volume and kind of criticism seems completely out of place. Yes, for most people COVID is history but that’s not the same as for everyone. There are viable reasons aside from mental trauma, theft and terror to wear a medical mask.

@MisterMiyagi According to pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC8805053 Covid-19 had a death rate of 0.03% among those infected by it. As a side note swine flu killed 0.05% of those infected by it during the initial outbreak. Swine flu is still around today, I don't see anyone panicking about it.

@Questor If you want to cherry pick biased papers at least cite them properly. The 0.03% is their number for the death rate for the entire world population regardless of infection.

@MisterMiyagi I really hope that there's more voice like yours in the office environment, this truly helps, thank you!
